# Meteor react js logged in user email

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I'm using meteor and react and Im trying to display the logged in user's email address

this is what im using

    `currentUserEmail() {
    return Meteor.user().emails[0].address;
    },
    render() {`

and in the return this is what I have

`<FlatButton label={this.currentUserEmail()} primary={true} />`

But Im getting `emails is not defined`

Ive tried to use

`<FlatButton label={Meteor.user().emails[0].address} primary={true} />`

directly but im stil getting email is  undefined
Help out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ive got the solution

`currentUserEmail() {
    var userId = Meteor.userId();
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userId});
    return user.emails[0].address;
    }`

and the flat button label

`<FlatButton label={this.currentUserEmail()} primary={true} />`